# Searching for user and returning the user information

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, winforms, return-value

When searching for a users full name and is found. I would like to retrieve the rest of the users info from all the table columns and display them in text boxes. Eg  textbox1=ID, textbox2=userInitials, textbox3=userEmail

When I run the code below, I receive the message box "User Found" but I don't know if this is actually working as I am not returning any values. How would I do this? Many thanks.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim searchQuery As String = "Select * from userInfoTable where [userFullName]= '" & SearchName.Text & "'"
    ExecuteQuery(searchQuery)
    MessageBox.Show("User Found.")
End Sub

Public Sub ExecuteQuery(query As String)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)

    connection.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Well -  `ExecuteNonQuery` is for SQL commands that **do not return** any data - like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. If you want to fetch data, you need to use either `ExecuteReader` and iterate over the rows returned by the reader, or fill a datatable with it

Comment: You ***need*** to learn how to parametrise your queries! This is wide open to injection, and thus is a *huge* security flaw.

Comment: Hi @Larnu I'm very new to the world of coding, can I ask what you mean by parametrise the queries and would you point me to a good learning source? Thanks.

Comment: [What is parameterized query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4712037/2029983)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ExecuteNonQuery()`, but that's for when you want to execute something that doesn't return a result set. In your case you *do* want the result set. So instead of that, you want to use `ExecuteReader()`, then read from the "reader" that gets returned. [Like this](http://vb.net-informations.com/ado.net-dataproviders/ado.net-executereader-executenonquery.htm).